# SQL Server Subquery a

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create trigger suadulieu22
on SACH
for update
as
    if UPDATE(MaTG) or UPDATE(MaNXB)
    begin 
        rollback tran
        print ('khong cho phep sua du lieu o cot MaTG va MaNXB')
    end

    if UPDATE(DonGia)
        if((select DonGia from inserted) >= 3600)
        begin
            rollback tran
            print 'don gia moi phai khong vuot qua 20% don gia cu '
        end

    update SACH
    set MaNXB = 'nxb1'
    where MaTG = 'tg1' and MaNXB = 'nxb1'

    update SACH
    set DonGia = 3060
    where MaTG = 'tg1' and MaNXB = 'nxb1'
```

Please help me, I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure suadulieu, Line 11
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
 if UPDATE(DonGia)
        if((select DonGia from inserted) >= (select DonGia from inserted)*1.2)
        begin
            rollback tran
            print 'don gia moi phai khong vuot qua 20% don gia cu '
        end
update SACH
set DonGia = 3060
where MaTG = 'tg1' and MaNXB = 'nxb1'
```

Comment: Triggers fire per statement in SQL Server, not per row. `if((select DonGia from inserted) >= 3600)` wont work correctly for multirow updates.

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. So, what do you expect `(select DonGia from inserted)` to return and how can those *multiple* values meaningfully be compared to 3600. *some* of them may match that condition. *some* may not.

Comment: can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an exists here in your conditional check. Most likely something like this. Without more details it is impossible to know what you are trying to do.

```
if EXISTS(
select MAX(DonGia) 
from inserted
having MAX(DonGia) >= (select MIN(DonGia) * 1.2 from inserted)
)
```

Comment: and run : " cập nhật SACH bộ DonGia = 3060 nơi MaTG = 'TG1 and MaNXB =' nxb1 ' "